# Failed to union two function results in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, union, iqueryable

I trying to union the result set of two SQL Table Function Calls and I keep getting this Error
 "The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.Parameter name: argument"

So far I have tried everything including "Make a primary key in function result table", "Adding a [key] attribute to result in entityframework model of function result" and nothing seems to work.

So this is my Linq syntax, I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

[image]

```c#
var dataPlan = Context.fn_GetPlans(3, 1, userId);
var dataPlan1 = Context.fn_GetPlans(3, 2, userId);

var ddataPlan = dataPlan.Union(dataPlan1);
```

Comment: the query builder in the example doesn't seem to support distinct in the result sets of the two functions, one thing you can do is to do that in-memory (i dont know the size of these sets), get the result by doing tolist on both function calls then do union between them, you will have to give a comparer for that. Alternatively make an SP which does this in SQL and returns you the net result.

Comment: Is the `fn_GetPlans_Result` type flat?

Comment: Thanks for the replies,
Yes, the ToList Functioning works but it is not an option in my case. you know.. because of the size and stuff.

And @HamletHakobyan, yes the function result is flat.

Comment: Use `Concat` in stead of `Union`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So far no answer ha worked for me since i wanted a way to keep the results in IQueryable,

So accepting that fact, I returned to my database and worked on the Database Function to return the result of multiple functions by itself and union them on the database side.

That worked for me, I hope everyone else having this problem, consider this solution in their work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by creating my own class that had the same properties as the function result type, and projecting the query to that class, e.g.:

```
var dataPlan = Context.fn_GetPlans(3, 1, userId)
    .Select(p => new MyClass
                 {
                     PropertyA = p.PropertyA,
                     PropertyB = p.PropertyB,
                     // ... etc...
                 });
```

I could not figure out why the original class did not work, but the new query could be Uninon'ed just fine.